# How to map color intensiy values to its name?

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a dominant color and a palette of color extracted from an image. I want to map those intensity values and print the name of dominant color and all the 
colors from color palette. I could extract those intensities values easily using Color_Thief. But how to map them with names?  This is what i have done so far:

[image]

I also have values prepared of color intensities in a list variable. These are the values:

[image]

Comment: Can you show expected result?

Comment: Have you tried webcolors? https://pypi.org/project/webcolors/1.3/ or do you want other type of conversion?

Comment: @Mntfr I have values in HSV format.

Comment: @Alderven basically i want to detect the color of fruit's image and print the name of color.

Comment: Ok, but what format of data do you expect? Or it is not necessary?

Comment: @Alderven Format is not necessary here. Output can be a line also like "Red color detected." and if there are more than one color then the percentage of that color with its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) together with [webcolors](https://pypi.org/project/webcolors/) to get color statistics for image:

```
import webcolors
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter

def get_colour_name(requested_colour):
    try:
        return webcolors.rgb_to_name(requested_colour)
    except ValueError:
        min_colours = {}
        for key, name_ in webcolors.css3_hex_to_names.items():
            r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
            rd = (r_c - requested_colour[0]) ** 2
            gd = (g_c - requested_colour[1]) ** 2
            bd = (b_c - requested_colour[2]) ** 2
            min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name_
        return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]

image = Image.open('image.jpg')
pixels = image.load()
w, h = image.size
colors = []
for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        colors.append(get_colour_name(pixels[x, y]))

for i, c in enumerate(Counter(colors).most_common(5)):
    print('{}. {:15} {:>2.1f}%'.format(i+1, c[0], c[1] * 100 / len(colors)))
```

For example for following image:

[image]

5 most common colors are:

```
1. crimson         10.3%
2. maroon          9.8%
3. darkslategrey   9.2%
4. dimgrey         8.4%
5. grey            8.1%
```